# Lineno splitting the document into hundreds of pages

Tags: line-numbering

I was trying to get all the lines numbered in my document, as explained in this question: [Show the number of lines in margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36226/show-the-number-of-lines-in-margin)

However, when I added the lines:

```
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
```

to the top of my document, the document got split into hundreds of pages - one line per page. How can I get it to work?

EDIT: The preamble of the document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,pra,aps,amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,tightenlines]{revtex4}

\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
```

EDIT 2: Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,pra,aps,amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath,tightenlines]{revtex4}

\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lineno}
\pagewiselinenumbers


\begin{document}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Coincidentally my test document also uses RevTeX - and doesn't show the same issue.  I think a full MWE would be in order.

Comment: @ChrisH, the example is provided now. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your MWE can be greatly reduced to be

```
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagewiselinenumbers

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

With such a simple MWE it becomes clear that the problem is an interaction between `revtex4` and `lineno`. Searching the `lineno` documentation yields:

> 1. if a class changes `\output` (APS journal class revtex4, e.g.), lineno.sty should be loaded by `\RequirePackage[here presumably following some options in brackets]{lineno}` preceding `\documentclass`.

Leading to a working MWE of

```
\RequirePackage{lineno}
\documentclass{revtex4}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagewiselinenumbers

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```