# Refer to a particular line of a page

Tags: cross-referencing, line-numbering

I am new to LaTeX, so I was probably quite naive to think that I will get a ready answer to this but to my surprise was not able to find an answer to this.

I just want to refer to a particular line of a particular page. So that I can say "see line 2 on Page 56" and it will automatically change when the document changes.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can do some simple things: make new counter, increment in every line (`\everycr{\stepcounter{counter}}`), set it to zero every page. But you can meet another problem: you won't be able to label other objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if there are any hidden caveats here, but you could use the `lineno` package for this. I've borrowed and modified the MWE from egreg's answer to [Reference the line number in which a (new) word occurred for the first time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36225/reference-the-line-number-in-which-a-new-word-occurred-for-the-first-time)

`lineno` lets you start the line numbering from 1 at each page by using `\pagewiselinenumbers`. I assume you don't want to display the numbers themselves, so I hid them by changing their colour to white.

Note that `\pagewiselinenumbers` require at least two compilation runs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lineno}
\pagewiselinenumbers
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\color{white}}
\begin{document}
In the traffic court of a large mid-western city, a young
lady was brought before the judge to answer a ticket given
her for driving through a red light. She explained to his
honor that she was a school teacher and requested an immediate
disposal\linelabel{disposal} of her case in order that she might hasten
on to her classes. A wild gleam came into the judge's eye.
"You are a school teacher, eh?" said he. "Madam, I shall
realize my lifelong ambition. Sit down at that table and
write 'I went through a red light' five hundred times."


Line \ref{disposal} on page \pageref{disposal}.

Line \ref{thing} on page \pageref{thing}.

\newpage

In the traffic court of a large mid-western city, a young
lady was brought before the judge to answer a ticket given
her for\linelabel{thing} driving through a red light. She explained to his
honor that she was a school teacher and requested an immediate
disposal of her case in order that she might hasten
on to her classes. A wild gleam came into the judge's eye.
"You are a school teacher, eh?" said he. "Madam, I shall
realize my lifelong ambition. Sit down at that table and
write 'I went through a red light' five hundred times."


\end{document}
```