# Why there is a huge extra blank space at the beginning of this document?

Tags: cross-referencing, incompatibility, line-numbering, lineno, pdfsync

After compiling following document, there is an extra blank space at the beginning of each page. I suspect there is an incompatibility between the **lineno** and pdfsync **package**. Is there a way to fix this problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\title{Title of article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\pagewiselinenumbers

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
In the traffic court of a large mid-western city, a young
lady was brought before the judge to answer a ticket given
her for driving through a red light. She explained to his
honor that she was a school teacher and requested an immediate
disposal\linelabel{disposal} of her case in order that she might hasten
on to her classes. A wild gleam came into the judge's eye.
"You are a school teacher, eh?" said he. "Madam, I shall
realize my lifelong ambition. Sit down at that table and
write 'I went through a red light' five hundred times."

Line \ref{disposal} on page \pageref{disposal}.
\end{document}
```

Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36234/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130947/.

Comment: do you need pdfsync? if you click on the pdfsync tag link below your question all it says is that it is incompatible with many packages and not needed in current distributions?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use `pdfsync` for inverse search between my document and my pdfviewer. I would be happy to keep it.

Comment: pdfsync was an early implementation of that facility but now it is built in to the tex executables in a much less intrusive way not needing the hooks to be added by a package see synctex

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118489/what-exactly-is-synctex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, removing `pdfsync` and using synctex seems to solve my problem. Thanks.